# Qual a vantagem de se usar um banco de dados para leitura e outro para escrita?

Tags: banco-de-dados, arquitetura-de-software, sincronização, replicação

Qual a vantagem/diferença de se usar bancos separados, sendo uma para leitura e outro para escrita?

Na minha concepção não existe esse conceito. O banco de escrita, uma hora terá que ser lido para replicar os dados no de leitura, que por sua vez sofrerá escrita para receber a replicação.

Até entendo que essa replicação poderia ocorrer em um horário onde o banco/sistema não está sendo tão usado, como de madrugada por exemplo, mas no meu caso, não posso me dar esse luxo, a sincronização/replicação entre os bancos tem que acontecer num intervalo máximo de 5 minutos.

Eu tenho um banco de dados hoje que sofre milhares de inserções por minuto, então se a cada 5 minutos eu rodar um processo de sincronização entre os bancos, acredito que serão milhões de linhas, e nesse momento, meu banco de leitura perderia performance pois estaria sofrendo com a escrita da replicação.

Estou considerando que essa replicação seria feita na "mão" através de um serviço desenvolvido por mim como se fosse uma fila, ou se usar os recursos de replicação existentes nos SGDBs, aí sim seria mais vantajoso/performático?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem alguns pontos que fazem muita diferença:

- **Read performance**: Se eu tenho mais máquinas disponíveis(read replicas) concorda que as leituras ficarão mais rápidas? Existe o balanceamento de carga distribuída entre as replicas.
- **Alta Disponibilidade**: Imagina se eu tenho apenas uma instância de banco de dados(read, write), por algum motivo a instância para de funcionar, toda sua aplicação que dependia do banco de dados também para de funcionar. Se eu tenho replicas do banco(seja elas apenas read replicas) minha aplicação não sofre um "outage", ela continua funcionando, mesmo que fique apenas com funcionalidades básicas (reads no banco de dados). Alta disponibilidade é um ponto muito importante para o seu negócio.
- **Durabilidade de Dados**: Se eu tenho N read replicas, logo, posso "perder" os dados de uma instância e rapidamente recupera-los(sem ter um backup da ultima hora) pois existem N replicas disponíveis com os dados.

Então:

> Pergunto isso, pois na minha concepção, não existe esse conceito. O banco de escrita, uma hora terá que ser lido para replicar os dados no de leitura, que por sua vez sofrerá escrita para receber a replicação.
>
> Até entendo que essa replicação poderia ocorrer em um horário onde o banco/sistema não está sendo tão usado, como de madrugada por exemplo, mas no meu caso, não posso me dar esse luxo, a sincronização/replicação entre os bancos tem que acontecer num intervalo máximo de 5 minutos.
>
> Eu tenho um banco de dados hoje que sofre milhares de inserções por minuto, então se a cada 5 minutos eu rodar um processo de sincronização entre os bancos, acredito que serão milhões de linhas, e nesse momento, meu banco de leitura perderia performance pois estaria sofrendo com a escrita da replicação.

Acredito que não seja bem assim o processo. Os gerenciadores de cluster possuem um processo de  cópia "mais inteligente" para não "estressar" seu banco de dados ao limite. Acho que aqui vale uma pesquisa mais profunda para entender melhor o funcionamento.

> Um último comentário, estou considerando que essa replicação seria feita na "mão" através de um serviço desenvolvido por mim como se fosse uma fila, ou se usar os recursos de replicação existentes nos SGDBs, aí sim seria mais vantajoso/performático?

Acredito que você não queira "escrever na mão" uma ferramenta de replicação. Deixe esse trabalho para as ferramentas de gerenciamento de cluster, por exemplo: [Galera Cluster](http://galeracluster.com)(MySQL Cluster) ou até mesmo a opção de [Read Replica do AWS RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/rds/details/read-replicas/).

Answer (score 4):

## Vantagens

- Maior escalabilidade (não performance)
- Maior confiabilidade na infraestrutura

## Detalhando

Geralmente não é bem assim que se faz. Existe um servidor que recebe as escritas e eventualmente pode receber leituras também. Existem outros servidores que só recebem leituras (o ganho começa ser interessante quando há alguns).

Geralmente você quer e pode ter leituras mais rápidas fazendo esta separação. Na maioria dos cenários é complicado ter grandes ganhos na escrita, é complicado separar. Claro que um servidor que tem prioridade para escrita é um auxílio.

É óbvio quer os servidores de leitura terão escritas, mas elas são mais leves porque o processamento necessário para fazer a escrita de forma correta já foi feito no servidor mestre, então não costuma pesar tanto.

Claro que cada caso é diferente. Por isso que esta n]ao é uma solução mágica. Existem situações que pode trazer ganhos que compense o aumento da complexidade.

Em geral a replicação é feita em tempo quase real (abaixo de 1ms de diferença, em alguns casos de forma síncrona onde o dado só é validado quando todos os escravos estão atualizados). A maioria dos cenários isto é importante.

É preciso muito cuidado para fazer este tipo de operação. Muita coisa pode dar errado.

A separação não dá mais performance, até come um pouco dela, apenas permite escalar mais. Você não conseguirá ter 3X a performance porque tem um servidor com escrita e outro com leitura, é mais provável que tenha 1.5X com esta configuração.

A maior confiabilidade é obtida já que tendo mais de um servidor um escravo pode assumir as funções se o mestre parar, ou o mestre pode continuar funcionando tudo se um escravo parar.

Também se um deles parar tem os mesmos dados no outro, assim não há perda.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).